# splitting file using random file access not working

Tags: java, file, io, random-access

i want to split a large file in to parts based on size .i used random access file .what i have done was getting the length of files splitting the files and setting file size for each file

```
File file = new File("/home/hello/test.txt");

if(file.exists()){
        long filesize = file.length();
        int noofparts = 5;
        int perfilesize = (int) (filesize/5);

for(int i=0;i<noofparts;i++){
            try {

                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/home/solomon/test"+i+".txt");
                RandomAccessFile racces = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
                racces.seek(seek);
                int read;

                 for(int j=0;j<perfilesize;perfilesize++){
                     os.write(racces.readInt());
                 }

                 os.flush();
                 os.close();





                 seek = seek+perfilesize;


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

it was splitting but not getting proper output

**INPUT**

> French police were searching the headquarters of Marine Le Pe

.....long text

**OUTPUT**

> rhl eaithqt MnensrgFttaeoa Manloo egontagmsfran doyrmaastaNfaoRe
>   eraaatsih hr Ferr

and the same output is written in the five files

Comment: Why would you split with random access when it's a text file that you're dealing with? Won't that risk making its text gibberish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your loop to

```
for(int j=0; j<perfilesize; j++){
```

Comment: also changing  os.write(racces.readInt()) to int read;
      
      for(int j=0;j<perfilesize;j++){
       read = racces.read();
       os.write(read);
      }